# How to setup PersistentStoreCoordinator and import from sqlite database on APP startup, without using main thread?

Tags: ios, core-data

So my first IOS APP was approved after only 1 rejection from Apple.

Problem is, being a perfectionist, I have a few issues with it from a Customer's point of view:

1) **PROBLEM**: It takes a while to download as the file size is too large. The size of the APP is 111MB, which then turns into an APP size of 222MB after the data is imported from the preloaded sqlite database into the Core Data database?
**Question** 1: Is there a way to delete the shipped database once data has been imported?  See my code A below?
**Question** 2: The actual sqlite database only contains a few photos (12MB) and a few columns, so why is it 111MB?  Is there a way to clean up a database? I tired the Vacuum command, using Liya, but that didn't seem to work.

2) **PROBLEM**: On startup the Splash screen is being displayed for about 8 seconds before the rest loads. This is because everything happens on the main thread.
**Question** 1: How do I setup the PersistentStoreCoordinator in another thread?  See code A  below.

3) **PROBLEM**: IOS burnout - anyone else who doesn't feel ready for IOS 8??  I guess working part-time, managing young kids, a house, a hubby and a dog leaves me with only 2 hours a day to work on my "little" project. I am teaching myself because I find courses out there only teach the basics and cost a fortune.  This site has been my life saver many times, I found more answers on here than in Apple's help files.

**CODE A - within the Appdelegate:**

## pragma mark - Core Data stack

```
// Returns the managed object context for the application.
// If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store        coordinator for the application.

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Recipes" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
 if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
    return _managedObjectModel;
}
 NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Recipes" withExtension:@"momd"];
_managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
return _managedObjectModel;
}

 // Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
 // If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to    it.
 - (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
 {
 if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
 }

  NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]       URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"SmoothieRecipes.sqlite"];

  //Set up the store.
  // For the sake of illustration, provide a pre-populated default store.

  NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
  // If the expected store doesn't exist, copy the default store.
  if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[storeURL path]]) {
      NSURL *defaultStoreURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"SmoothieRecipes"   withExtension:@"sqlite"];
     if (defaultStoreURL) {
        [fileManager copyItemAtURL:defaultStoreURL toURL:storeURL error:NULL];
     }
  }

   NSError *error = nil;
  _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:  [self managedObjectModel]];


  NSDictionary *options =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        //[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSSQLiteManualVacuumOption,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],   NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption,    nil];



  if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil   URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {

NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
  }    

   [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:storeURL];

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
**strong text** }
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way to delete your preload data from the app bundle.  It is read only.

As to the size of the sqlite database, there is overhead.  I have one I use that before any records are written to it, it approaches 100K, so perhaps 200K+ may not be far off depending on what all you have in there.  Keep in mind any indexes would be present, as well as layout information for all your tables (entities).

I've not done Core Data on a background thread but it sounds as though you could create a separate core data stack in its own class, and create a managed object context with NPPrivateQueueConcurrencyType.  This will

The easiest way to perform Core Data operations in the background is to create a managed object context of the NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType. This will put it in a background thread.

As to "burnout" I'm in a similar situation to you; I own a software business that is unrelated to iOS in the daytime, handling installation & support calls.  Development is night time and weekends only.  I get in the office at 10am and stay until 6pm, then work on iOS software from about 10pm until 2-3am.  I'm ready for this project to be done. I can't imagine having young kids and doing it.  I've been writing software for 40 years and learning Objective C for me has been difficult.  At 60 you don't remember stuff like you used to ;)

One of the biggest problems for me as the only person in my business writing software is when you have questions or problems there really isn't anyone to sit and discuss it with; as a result you don't really know if you're doing things in the easiest possible way sometimes.

I agree this forum has been invaluable to me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  Will go lookup NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType now.  Good luck to you, one day one of your APPs will strike it rich;-)